# Not able to set width of ImageView in WindowManager

Tags: android, imageview, android-windowmanager

I have been developing app for chat heads Android.
I have created a service such as below. This service is started by the MainActivity.

```
public class StatusBarService extends Service {


private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead ;
int BUFFER = 60;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);





    chatHead = new ImageView(this);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    chatHead.setLayoutParams(vp);



    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           100,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR  ,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

}
```

[image: I am getting this .]

I want to set the width for the same. Currently I am not able to do it.

I tried changing lot of parameters for LayoutParams . I feel the issue is with imageview not able to fill up the WindowManager View .
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: It will automatically take that particular size of your Imageview. What size you want to give?

Comment: Match parent is the size. It's not doing so.

Comment: Please wrap the view in a pseudo container view (Like a liner layout). It worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap the view in a pseudo container view (Like a liner layout). It worked for me. :)